# Sum of permutations of a number

Tags: number-theory, permutations

If I have a number (without any 0's) such as 1112334, how would I sum the permutations of its digits (excluding duplicates)? I am assuming there is a closed form involving factorials or combinatorics.

Comment: Just so that I'm clear about what you're asking, do you mean that if your number were $21$ then you'd want to find $21+12=33$?

Comment: If the number were 21 then the permutations would be 12 and 21, which sum to 33. If the number were 221 then the permutations would be 221, 212, 122.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $d_j$ be the number of digits $j$ in an $n$-digit number with no $0$'s.  Thus
$\sum_{j=1}^9 d_j = n$.  The number of distinct permutations of these digits is $M = n!/(d_1! d_2! \ldots d_9!)$.  The number of these where the $k$'th digit is $j$ is $M d_j/n$.  Thus the sum of all the permutations is
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n 10^{k-1} \sum_{j=1}^9 j M d_j/n = \dfrac{(10^n-1) M}{9n} \sum_{j=1}^9 j d_j $$
For your example $1112334$, we have $n=7$, $d_1=3$, $d_2=1$, $d_3=2$, $d_4=1$, all other $d_j = 0$, $M = 420$, and the sum is
$ 999999900$.

EDIT: See also OEIS sequence [A045876](https://oeis.org/A045876).

Comment: I have two questions: 1. How is the distinct number of permutations $n!$ over all $d_j!$ values? 2. How do you know that the number of cases where the $k$th digit is $j$ is $Md_j/n$?

Comment: 1.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets
2. After specifying that this digit is $j$, use the same formula but with $n$ replaced by $n-1$ and $d_j$ replaced by $d_j-1$.