# Sum of permutations of a number, including zero digits

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, permutations

The question [Sum of permutations of a number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352997/sum-of-permutations-of-a-number) asks for a formula for the sum of all the permutations a number, but excluding numbers with zero digits. Is there a similar formula for numbers with $0s$ in it?

So for instance:

$$120 \,\, --> \,012 + 021 + 102 + 120 + 201 + 210 = 666$$

Comment: The digital sum for $~120~$ is easily computed as $$3! \times \left[~A \times ~\left( ~100 + 10 + 1 ~\right) ~\right],$$ where $~A~$ represents the average value of the digits.  In the case of $~120,~$ this value is $~\dfrac{0 + 1 + 2}{3}.~$  This type of reasoning will hold when taking the digital sum of any number, regardless of whether $~0~$ is one of the digits.

Comment: Thanks, but the formula seems to be off. For instance for 1200 I would expect 9999, but the formula gives 19998, while for 1112334 I would expect 999999900, but I get 11999998800.

Comment: For $~1200~$ there are $~\dfrac{4!}{2!} = 12~$ different permutations, with the average size of the digits equal to $~\dfrac{0 + 0 + 1 + 2}{4} = \dfrac{3}{4}.~$  So, the formula gives $$12 \times \frac{3}{4} \times [1000 + 100 + 10 + 1].$$

Comment: This solves my question, if you want to post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is the same, regardless of whether one or more of the digits is $~0.$  Assume that there are $~n~$ (not necessarily distinct) digits.  Assume that there are B distinct ways of permuting the digits.  Assume that the average value of the digits is $~A.$

Then, the formula is

$$B \times A \times [~10^{n-1} + 10^{n-2} + 10^{n-3} + \cdots + 1].$$

---

Examples:

- Digits are $~0,1,2.$ 
  $A = ~\dfrac{0 + 1 + 2}{3}, ~B = 3!, ~n = 3.$
- Digits are $~0,0,1,2.$ 
  $A = ~\dfrac{0 + 0 + 1 + 2}4, ~B = \dfrac{4!}{2!}, ~n=4.$
- Digits are $~1,1,1,2,3,3,4.$ 
  $A = ~\dfrac{1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 4}7, ~B = \dfrac{7!}{3!\times 2!}, ~n=7.$

Comment: If $m_i$ is the multiplicity of the digit $i$ and $$n = m_0 + m_1 + m_2 + m_3 + m_4 + m_5 + m_6 + m_7 + m_8 + m_9,$$ then $$A = \frac{0m_0 + 1m_1 + 2m_2 + 3m_3 + 4m_4 + 5m_5 + 6m_6 + 7m_7 + 8m_8 + 9m_9}{n}$$ and $$B = \frac{n!}{m_0!m_1!m_2!m_3!m_4!m_5!m_6!m_7!m_8!m_9!}$$